# Non abstract class cannot override abstract method compareTo in Comparable?

Tags: java, interface, abstract, comparable

I have a class `Vertex<T>` which implements `IVertex<T>` which implements `Comparable`. Whenever, I compile my code, I get the error:

> Vertex is not abstract and does not override abstract method
>   compareTo(IVertex) in Comparable

The issue with this is that, I CANNOT change any of the code within the interface `IVertex` as that is what my teacher has instructed. How can I solve this issue? I have included my code below:

Vertex:

```
 package student_solution;


import graph_entities.*;

import java.util.*;

public class Vertex<T> implements IVertex<T>{

  // Add an edge to this vertex.

  public void addEdge(IEdge<T> edge){

  } 

  // We get all the edges emanating from this vertex:  

    public Collection< IEdge<T> > getSuccessors(){

    }

    // See class Label for an an explanation:

    public Label<T> getLabel(){

    }

    public void setLabel(Label<T> label){

    }

  }
```

IVertex:

```
package graph_entities;

import java.util.Collection;

public interface IVertex<T> extends Comparable<IVertex<T>>
{

  // Add an edge to this vertex.

  public void addEdge(IEdge<T> edge);

  // We get all the edges emanating from this vertex:  

public Collection< IEdge<T> > getSuccessors();

  // See class Label for an an explanation:

public Label<T> getLabel();

public void setLabel(Label<T> label);

}
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Well, implement the method you forgot to implement (i.e. `public int compareTo(IVertex<T> v)`.

Comment: The compiler is telling you that your class has to implement the compareTo method - that's all.

Comment: Read the error message more carefully. It says `Vertex`, not `IVertex`.

Answer (score 2):

As the error suggests, your class implements an `interface` which extends `Comparable`. Now, in order to make your class concrete, you have to `override` all the methods of `interfaces` your class is implementing.

So, in your case, all you need to do is to override `compareTo` method in Vertex `class`, e.g.:

```
@Override
public int compareTo(IVertex<T> o) {
    // implementation
    return 0;
}
```

[Here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/createinterface.html)'s Oracle's documentation on interfaces and inheritance.

Comment: Yes, mostly, but the method he needs to implement is not `compareTo(T)` but rather `compareTo(IVertex<T>)`.  That could turn out to be a design problem, depending on how the comparison is supposed to be implemented.

Comment: @JohnBollinger thanks for pointing it out. I missed it :( And yes, it could well turn out to be a design problem but as OP is instructed not to change the `interface`, we can't do much.

Comment: Thank you! I think I panicked when I saw the commandline error. Beginners mistake.